# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to get the text of a textfield in mainApp when app is closing

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I am new to javaFX and i am trying to get the value of a text field when my application is closing so i used

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
FXMLController controllerClass = loader.getController();
loader.load();
controllerClass.getTextFieldValue();
System.out.println("closing");
```

inside

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest()
```

but i always get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

this is getTextfieldValue()

```
System.out.println(textField.getText());
```

so basically this is what I want to achieve, I want to get the value in a text field when the my application is closing. so I have my `stage.onCloseRequest()` method in my mainApp class but the textField.getText() is always returning an empty string. And I want it to return the current text in the textField.

Answer (score 2):

You must run `load()` before you get the controller.

Try this code:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
loader.load();
FXMLController controllerClass = loader.getController();
controllerClass.getTextFieldValue();
System.out.println("closing");
```

Comment: the NullPointerException disappered but the getTextFieldValue is printing an empty string even if there is a string in the textfield

Comment: Your original question doesn't seem to provide enough context for me to answer that question. For example, what is textField in your getTextfieldValue() method?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and quick reply, @FXML TextField textField; is the textfield I  want to get the text in it when I am closing my application.

Comment: My suggestion would be to check that you're getting the right textField aka the one that corresponds with the one you want to get the text from.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add `fx:id` in your `Scene.fxml`?
Please, provide more example of your code. I don't know what's happening in your `FXML` file. I think there may be some kind of xml code missing.

Although I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I think there is easier and correct way to do it.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml")));
loader.setController(new FXMLController()); // you can not get controller, unless you set it first
FXMLController controllerClass = loader.getController();
controllerClass.getTextFieldValue();
```

This always be `null` if you do not set value to `getTextFieldValue` before

Comment: Thanks for the help, the fx:id is correct, my only problem now is that I can't get the current value of the text field. Its always printing out an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

- To remove the NullPointerException first run `load()` before you get the controller.
- To get the value of the textfield when closing the application, I used the Preferences class from java.util.prefs to save the content of the textfield, then I overrode the `stop()` method in my mainApp and got back the saved value in it.

---

Not sure this is the best way to do it but it worked for me, Thanks for all the help.